# How can I save my favourites in KNR search and launch page?

Tags: knr

Using lucid Kubunu Network Release, every time I reboot some of my favourites are missing. Do I have to log out in order to save them? How can I do that without  logging out?

Comment: What application are you using?

Comment: i.e. quassel. However, it is irrelevant what I add there, I can add anything that is available through the menu structure. The issue is, that after login out and in again, the favorites are the defaults again.

Comment: What is KNR search and launch page?
It seems to be a website, so it's not related to Ubuntu!

Comment: KNR means Kubuntu Netbook Remix

Comment: Which version of KDE SC are you using?

Comment: 4.4.2. the standard of lucid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the favourites in Kickoff and S&L are separate lists.  Click the gold star on the ones you find on the S&L page to put them in the Favourites section.  If they're not staying put, report a bug.

Comment: Yeah. I think it is a bug. I will report it.